# How to make this button scroll through multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example im trying to make a scroll button that would scroll down multiple divs.

This is some example code of what i mean.

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
```

I know how to make the button scroll too just one div but i cant figure out how to make the button first scroll to 1 then 2 then 3 and etc.

Here is the code for the button

```
<section id="scrolldownButton" class="button">
            <a href=""><span></span>Scroll</a>
</section>

$(function() {
           $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
                   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 500, 'linear');
                        });
                });
```

Try it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500, 'linear');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>

<section id="scrolldownButton" class="button">
  <a href=""><span></span>Scroll</a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can set a class on the current `active` element, then use `next()` to find the element to scroll to the next time the button is clicked. Once you reach the end of the elements you want to scroll through you can go back to the start. Note that I added a common `content` class to the `div` elements to make this more reliable. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $('.content.active').next('.content');
    if ($target.length == 0)
      $target = $('.content:first');
      
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $target.addClass('active');
      
    $('html, body').animate({ 
      scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    }, 500, 'linear');
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 250px;
}

#scrolldownButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 50px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="content active">1</div>
<div id="2" class="content">2</div>
<div id="3" class="content">3</div>
<div id="4" class="content">4</div>
<div id="5" class="content">5</div>

<section id="scrolldownButton" class="button">
  <a href="#">Scroll</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I tried doing this and it would only go to the the active div but it would not scroll to the other divs.

Comment: hey nvm i found out what was wrong and fixed it. Thank you for the help!